# Convergence: Weak vs. Strong

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Suppose one has:
$$\|\varphi\|=\lim_n\|\varphi_n\|$$
Then it follows:
$$\varphi\rightharpoonup\varphi\implies\varphi_n\to\varphi$$

How can I check this?

Comment: $\|u_n-n\|^{2}=\|u_n\|^2-(u_n,u)-(u,u_n)+\|u\|^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... you just have to show $\|\varphi_n - \varphi\| \to 0$. But $$\|\varphi_n-\varphi\|^2 = \|\varphi_n\|^2 - \langle \varphi_n,\varphi\rangle -\langle \varphi,\varphi_n\rangle + \|\varphi\|^2.$$

Now, by assumption the first term converges to $\|\varphi\|^2$, the second and third term converge (by assumption of weak convergence) to $\langle \varphi,\varphi\rangle=\|\varphi\|^2$.