# Isometries: Weak vs. Strong

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider isometries:
$$R_\lambda\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad R_\lambda^*R_\lambda=1$$

Then it follows:
$$R_\lambda\rightharpoonup R\implies R_\lambda\to R$$

How can I check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Meanwhile I got it: False!*

Given the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Consider right shifts:
$$R_n:\ell^2(\mathbb{N})\to\ell^2(\mathbb{N}):\quad R_n:=R^n$$

They are isometric:
$$\|R^n\varphi\|=\|\varphi\|\quad(\varphi\in\ell^2)$$
But only weakly
$$R_n\rightharpoonup0\quad R_n\not\to0$$

Concluding counterexample.

*See also: [Weak vs. Strong](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/893096/79762)*